# In House distribution profile

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

So I've read that I don't need any UDID to distribute my app to my client devices.

The problem is that I can't find the option to generate that kind of provisioning profile on my iOS dev center.

What is the process ? Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you have a AppStore developers account or Enterprise developers account? Since the InHouse Profiles can only be create with an Enterprise account. Also the some restrictions to this, as you can officially only distribute to employees of the company under which the  Enterprise account is created.

Comment: AH ok I didn't know, I have a regular AppStore developer 100$ account. That means I can't distribute my app if I don't have the devices UDID's at all ?

Comment: Nope there is not InHouse profiles for the AppStore developers account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a AppStore developers account or Enterprise developers account?

Since the InHouse Profiles can only be create with an Enterprise account. Also the some restrictions to this, as you can officially only distribute to employees of the company under which the Enterprise account is created.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have another one : What is the process with an Enterprise account to deploy app on a device ?

Comment: You have to provide a secure download of you app. You can use for example TestFlightApp, HockeyApp, etc... or deployment with the device manager.